# Modify .torrent file in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing an application to download torrent file and modify it's tracker link (just replace passkey). But probably I have big problem with encoding because when I save modified file it can't be open in my torrent client.

I wrote a code to download and modify file:

```
@Override
public void exeucte(String link) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        URL website = new URL(link);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        String fileName = getFileName(link);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        replacePassKey(fileName);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null)
            fos.close();
    }

}

private void replacePassKey(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File originalFile = new File(fileName);
    String lines = readLines(originalFile);
    String replacedLines = lines.replaceAll("(.*passkey=)(.*)(:comment27.*)", "$1" + PASS_KEY + "$3");
    originalFile.delete();
    writeReplacedLines(replacedLines, originalFile);
}

private void writeReplacedLines(String replacedLines, File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        bw.write(replacedLines);
    } finally {
        if (bw != null)
            bw.close();
    }

}

private String readLines(File originalFile) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile raf = null;
    String lines = null;
    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(originalFile, "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) raf.length()];
        raf.read(bytes);
        lines = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    } finally {
        if (raf != null)
            raf.close();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

I'm sure that downloading works because I can open not modified file in torrent client (also when I modify downloaded file in KomodoEdit). But when I modify file and save replaced String my client can't open it and complains about invalid data.

Anyone has any idea? Maybe UTF8 is wrong or I have to change some part of my code?

Comment: I'm guessing the file is supposed to be in ASCII or a variation of. So direct output in UTF-8 would not be suitable.

Comment: Is there any way to check downloaded file's encoding? On wiki there is information about UTF-8 in torrent file.

Comment: The torrent files on my computer are showing as ANSI... Source - Open with Windows Notepad and try to save as. at the bottom it shows the detected encoding in a drop down box.

Comment: It works when I use FileUtils (from apache commons) and force reading and writing charset to "MacRoman". But I don't think that the "MacRoman" is encoding that I should use...

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it with various settings and check [the wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.